# How can D3 select multiple shapes with shared attributes from a group?

Tags: d3.js

How can D3 select multiple shapes in a group with shared attributes?

I'm building a chart in D3 where each datapoint is represented by a number of shapes. I have a simple data set, and I create a group with three separate sets of shapes bound to that.

I want the shapes on a row to change colour as I mouseover and mouseout.  There are two functions - "over" and "out" - which I call on mouseover.  They successfully change the objects' style properties, but for each set of shapes in turn.

The code below and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajlund/vCcH6/5/) illustrate the problem.

This approach doesn't scale across shapes, and it feels like I'm missing a key point about D3's select. Can I can select all objects with a shared index (or other attribute) in one step?

I have tried various approaches:

- select("shapes").filter(...)
- select("shapes")[0][i]

but have not succeeded in getting these to work.

```
var dataset = ["A", "B", "C"];

// Create SVG object
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({width: 600, height: 400});

var shapes = svg.append("g");

// Circles
var circles = shapes.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id",function(d, i) {return i;})
    .attr("cx",125)
    .attr("cy",function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100-25;})
    .attr("r",25)
    .on("mouseover", over)
    .on("mouseout", out)
    .append("title").text(function(d, i) {return d + " " + i;});

// Ellipses
var ellipses = shapes.selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", 350)
    .attr("cy",function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100-25;})
    .attr("rx",50)
    .attr("ry",25)
    .on("mouseover", over)
    .on("mouseout", out)
    .append("title").text(function(d, i) {return d + " " + i;});

// Squares
var squares = shapes.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 200)
    .attr("y",function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100-50;})
    .attr("height",50)
    .attr("width",50)
    .on("mouseover", over)
    .on("mouseout", out)
    .append("title").text(function(d, i) {return d + " " + i;});

// Over function to be called on mouseover
function over(d, i) {
    shapes.selectAll("circle").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", "green");
    shapes.selectAll("rect").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", "green");
    shapes.selectAll("ellipse").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", "green");
}

// Out function to be called on mouseout
function out(d, i) {
    shapes.selectAll("rect").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", null);
    shapes.selectAll("circle").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", null);
    shapes.selectAll("ellipse").filter(function(e, j) {return j == i;})
        .style("fill", null);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to handle groups of elements if you bunch them together with `g` elements. In your case, you would have one `g` for each row and attach the elements and handlers to that. Then, on mouse events, you simply need to select all the descendant elements of the group to operate on.

I've modified your jsfiddle to that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vCcH6/6/). The key things are the creation of the groups

```
var gs = shapes.selectAll("g").data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("id",function(d, i) {return i;})
  .attr("transform",function(d, i) {return "translate(0," + i*100 + ")";})
  .on("mouseover", over)
  .on("mouseout", out);
```

and the much-simplified event handlers

```
function over(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).selectAll("*").style("fill", "green");
}
```

Comment: The key point here for me (and it seems obvious now) is that groups can have data bound to them and child elements seamlessly inherit the parent group's data.

Comment: Data can be bound to any elements, regardless what they actually represent. Data inheritance doesn't work quite this way -- by default, nothing is inherited (and in this case it doesn't need to). If you use `select` to make a subselection, data will be inherited, but not if you use `selectAll` -- see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select).